# How to group by documents by a particular field inside a folder in a library

Tags: 2013, document-library

I have a document library and I have multiple folders and sub folders. I have added many documents inside sub folder and I have field in that library called PO Number and I want to group those documents based on this PO Number. But when I try to do that top level folders are also getting grouped by this field. How can I mak it apply only to he documents inside sub folders. when I group by the documents it shouldn't apply to the top folders. is there a way to achieve this. please help

Thanks

Comment: Not out of the box. You'll need to develop something custom.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @jpollar, however depending on your solution you could create a view that filters to that particular folder, flatens the list, and groups by PO Number, that way even though technically it will be grouping the folders as well it wouldn't matter.